# Cisco ASA 5505 to replace a Cisco PIX

Tags: vpn, cisco-asa, cisco-pix

Is a Cisco ASA 5505 powerful / capable enough to replace a Cisco PIX 503 ?

The PIX runs about 10 site to site VPN's and 40+ individual users on vpn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit**: Sorry, I was reading the tech specs wrong. You need a 5510 to support over 25 vpn clients. The Security Plus bundle and the Anyconnect Essentials bundle still apply.

Yes, it has more power under the bonnet than a PIX 506E.

You get exactly 10 ipsec licenses with the standard version, with Security Plus (bundle) you'll get 25 ipsec licenses, unlimited users and 2 SSL vpn peers.

If you need to support 40+ remote clients (not ipsec site to site) then a Anyconnect Essentials bundle is worth the money. AFAIK we got the 250-user license very cheap.

Answer (score 4):

No, the 5505 only supports 25 VPN users.

Upon further investigation, it supports 25 ipsec clients, and 25 AnyConnect, but not sure if that's concurrent.

Comment: Anyconnect without SSL is ipsec, so I think it counts both.

Answer (score 0):

The 5505 is fairly limited in the number of concurrent VPN connections it will accept.  The 5510 can handle more, and probably everything your Pix could, but you'll have to pay for the licenses.